# How can I remove a file based on its creation date time in Perl?

Tags: perl, file

My webapp is hosted on a unix server using MySQL as database.

I wrote a Perl script to run backup of my database. The Perl script is inside the *cgi-bin* folde and it is working. I only need to set the cronjob and run the Perl script once a day.

The backups are stored in a folder named *db_backups*,. However, I also want to add a command inside my Perl script to remove any files inside the folder *db_backups* that are older than say 10 days ago.

I have searched high and low for unix commands and cannot find anything that matches what I needed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`if (-M $file > 10) { unlink $file }`

or, coupled with `File::Find::Rule`

```
my $ten_days_ago = time() - 10 * 86400;
my @to_delete = File::Find::Rule->file()
  ->mtime("<=$ten_days_ago")
  ->in("/path/to/db_backup");
unlink @to_delete;
```

Comment: by the way, any resources to help me to learn perl faster? i know some simple php and java. i am not very good. and most online resources i dont really can understand. i heard perl is very good for text manipulation so i wanted to learn that to automate most of the tasks i do.

Comment: @keisimone: O'Reilly has a book called "Learning Perl"

Answer (score 5):

On Unix you can't, because *the file's creation date is not stored in the filesystem*.

You may want to check out [stat](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat.html), and [-M](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html) (modification time)/[-C](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html) (*inode change time*)/[-A](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html) (access time) if you want a simple expression with relative timestamps (how long ago).

Comment: A good point, and important to understand, but considering the usage pattern of a "backup file", mtime is as good as creation time :)

Comment: There is also File::CreationTime, which stores some data out-of-band that lets you get a file's creation time.  The creation time starts off as the mtime, but after you change the file, the creation time sticks around.   (This works surprisingly well.)

Answer (score 2):

> *i have searched high and low for unix commands
>   and cannot find anything that matches what i needed.*

Check out [`find(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) and [`xargs(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs).  Warning:  these commands may change your life at the shell prompt.

```
$ find /path/to/backup -type f -mtime +10 -print0 | xargs -0 echo rm -f
```

When you're confident that will Do What You Want (tm), remove the `echo`.  It says, roughly, starting in `/path/to/backup`, descend looking for plain files whose *mtime* is greater than 10 days,  and print their names to `xargs`, which will pass those names to `rm` in batches.

(`print0` and its complement `-0` are GNU extensions -- you mentioned you were on Linux -- which let you deal with whitespace in filenames safely.)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it without resorting to Unix commands. Loop through the files in your directory, use [`stat`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat.html) on each file to get its last modify time for a file, then use [`unlink`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unlink.html) on the file to delete it if it's older than what you want.